# Effect of star's binding energy due to general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, stars

Due to the curvature of space-time the distances near the star are length contracted. So if that's the case then doesn't that mean that the binding energy of star should be more since the distance between particles is less due to length contraction of general relativity.

Comment: Could you specify what is exactly the question ? Thanks.

Comment: @FredericThomas I mean the deviation between binding energy calculated from Newton's laws and general relativity( by this i mean length contraction of space time inside the star causing the value to deviate from Newton's laws)

Comment: "*the distance between particles is less due to length contraction*" - In length contraction, distances measured locally are longer than coordinate distances.

Answer (score 1):

The effects of length contraction and binding energy are all accounted for via the Einstein field equation, but unpacking all such effects and saying which effect made which contribution is not always possible. For example, when you say the binding energy is 'more', the question is 'more than what?' and then, if you want to be precise, how are you proposing to calculate exactly how much of the energy to call binding energy? It is not a trivial issue because spacetime itself influences all calculations of total energy, when there is curvature. As a result we can only refer to things like total rest mass, and define them unambiguously, by extending integrals to the asymptotic limit, far from gravitating bodies, where there is no curvature.

*Some more info. after a couple of comments were added*

As an example of the question 'compared to what'? consider a static spherical star. Define the surface to be the location where the pressure goes to zero. Let $R$ be the proper distance from the centre to the surface, and let $A$ be the surface area. Then, owing to positive spatial curvature, 
$A < 4 \pi R^2$. If we wanted to compare this to a Newtonian situation (i.e. one without spatial curvature) then should we compare with a star of the same radius or the same surface area?

Comment: Actually the answer to the question could be made precise if we consider the problem within the framework that allows unified consideration of both GR solutions and their Newtonian limits such as “frame theory” of J. Ehlers (see e.g. [here](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/14/1A/010), especially section 5).

Comment: The binding energy is defined by the gravitational potential, which in turn is defined by the gravitational time dilation. The simplest example is a photon. Its binding energy is defined by the redshift, which is easily calculated in case of the Schwarzschild metric. Energy and time are Fourier conjugates, if you know one, you know the other.

Answer (score 0):

> Due to the curvature of space-time the distances near the star are length contracted.

Not true. Curvature and length contraction are two different things.

Comment: The quote is correct. The Schwarzschild metric describes curvature of spacetime as the time dilation (curvature of time) and the radial distance contraction (curvature of space). Outside the horizon, the coordinate distance $r$ is shorter (contracted) than the proper distance measured along a static slice of spacetime: $$ ds=\left(1-\dfrac{r_s}{r}\right)^{-1/2}\,dr $$